# mongodb, Impact of collection data structure on performance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, data-structures

on the define the collection data structure, how to judge which structure is a good design or decision? This will affect the subsequent access to the database performance.

for example:

when the one data like this:

```
{
    _id:'a'
    index:1,   //index 1~n
    name:'john'
}
```

When n is large, meaning that data will be large and frequent deposited.

the collection data structure will be to `one dimensional object`:

```
{
    _id:'a'
    index:1,   
    name:'john'
}
.
.
.
{
    _id:'a'
    index:99,   
    name:'jule'
}
```

Or a `composite two-dimensional object`:

```
{
    _id:'a'
    info:[
        {index:1,name:'john'},...,{index:99,name:'jule'}   
    ]
}
```

`composite two-dimensional object` can effectively reduce the number of data, however, the search method is not convenient for writing, and whether it will actually reduce the effectiveness of searching or depositing a database.

Or the number of data is the key to affecting the effectiveness of the database.

Comment: If you will be infinitely adding onto the array inside a single document. I believe that is going to trigger reassignment of memory for the document. I also heard that mongodb is very good at "finding a needle from a haystack"

Comment: Suppose the array is limited, such as a size of 50,000 composite two-dimensional object, and were disassembled into 50,000 data. Which one is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Better" means different things to different use cases. What works in your case might not necessarily work in other use cases.

Generally, it is better to avoid large arrays, due to:

1. MongoDB's document size limitation (16MB).
2. Indexing a large array is typically not very performant.

However, this is just a general observation and not a specific rule of thumb. If your data lends itself to an array-based representation and you're certain you'll never hit the 16MB document size, then that design may be the way to go (again, specific to your use case).

You may find these links useful to get started in schema design:

- [6 Rules of Thumb for MongoDB Schema Design: Part 1](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1)
- [Part 2](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87892923503/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2)
- [Part 3](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/88473035333/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3)
- [Data Models](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/data-modeling/)
- [Use Cases](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/)
- [Query Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/)
- [Explain Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/)

Comment: This means that when I search `_id`, the `composite two-dimensional object` structure is more appropriate. When I search `info`, one dimensional object is more appropriate?

Comment: @AlbertChen it really depends on how you design your app, and which information in the documents is more relevant to you. There is no right or wrong. The links I posted should give you an idea. One thing is to let your application design govern how the database is structured, and not the other way around like in typical SQL design, where you have to design how your data is structured first.

Comment: @AlbertChen also make sure that you test your design with your expected workload before committing to production. See if you have any performance issues with it.